# Join a channel in Programmable chat on Twilio as channel admin to send media in message

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, twilio-programmable-chat

I am trying to send media messages in programmable chat on Twilio. But as per the docs, only **Channel admin** and **Channel user** roles can send media messages.
When I create my chatClient, it automatically assigns them with **Service admin** and **Service User** role. How can I join the channel as a channel admin or channel user so that i can send media messages.

Below is the code I am using for creating chat client and joining the channel:

```
 initChat = () => {
    this.chatClient = new Chat(this.state.token);
    this.chatClient.initialize().then(this.clientInitiated.bind(this));
  };

clientInitiated = () => {
    this.setState({ chatReady: true }, () => {
      this.chatClient
        .getChannelByUniqueName(this.channelName)
        .then(channel => {
          if (channel) {
            return (this.channel = channel);
          }
        })
        .catch(err => {
          if (err.body.code === 50300) {
            return this.chatClient.createChannel({
              uniqueName: this.channelName
            });
          }
        })
        .then(channel => {
          this.channel = channel;
          window.channel = channel;
          if (channel.state.status !== "joined") {
            console.log("New member joining in");
            return this.channel.join();
          } else {
            console.log("already joined the channel earlier");
            return this.channel;
          }
        })
        .then(() => {
          console.log("Channel: ", this.channel);
          this.channel.getMessages().then(this.messagesLoaded);
          this.channel.on("messageAdded", this.messageAdded);              
        });
    });
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

From [the documentation](https://www.twilio.com/docs/chat/permissions):

> #### Roles and Role Scopes
>
> Chat Roles are divided into two "Scopes," Service and Channel. These
>   determine how the Role permissions are applied depending on the
>   context.
>
> - Service level Roles are assigned to Users and dictate which Channels the User can see, join, and create.
> - Channel level Roles are assigned to Members within a Channel. These roles determine what Members can do within that Channel, such as send Messages, add other Members, edit Messages and more.

So, while your chat client has a service role, your user's member in a channel will have a channel level role like channel admin or channel user and will be able to send media messages.

Check out the [docs on roles and permissions](https://www.twilio.com/docs/chat/permissions) and the [REST API for roles](https://www.twilio.com/docs/chat/rest/roles) for more information.